# Stress tensor of fluid in equilibrium, inertial frame

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

There are some points in this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Stress%E2%80%93energy_of_a_fluid_in_equilibrium) chapter. Main equation is:

$$ T^{\alpha \beta} \, = \left(\rho + {p \over c^2}\right)u^{\alpha}u^{\beta} + p g^{\alpha \beta} $$

where $c$ is explicit.

The one for the trace is:

$$T  = 3p - \rho c^2$$

that seems contradictory with:

$$T^{\alpha\beta} = \left( \begin{matrix}
                   \rho & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & p & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & 0 & p & 0 \\
                   0 & 0 & 0 & p    
      \end{matrix} \right)$$

with trace $3p+\rho$ (difference in sign and value of last term).

The expression for the four-velocity:

$$u^{\alpha} = (1, 0, 0, 0)$$

is not the usual one $(c, 0, 0, 0)$.

Finally, the metric:

$$g^{\alpha\beta} \, = \left( \begin{matrix}
                   - c^{-2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
                   0 & 0 & 0 & 1    
      \end{matrix} \right)$$

also with explicit $c$, it is also not the usual:

$$\left( \begin{matrix}
                   -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
                   0 & 0 & 0 & 1    
      \end{matrix} \right)$$

Are the wikipedia equations in this chapter using a coherent notation ? If yes, how to explain the previous points ?

Comment: Thinking of tensors as "matrices" always ended up confusing me. In fact, I believe you can't strictly take a trace of an object like $T^{\mu\nu}$, since this quantity will turn out to be basis dependent. I find it better to think of the "trace" for such objects to be $g_{\mu\nu} T^{\mu\nu}$. See [this answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/279904/157014).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trace is ${T^\mu}_\mu$ not $T^{\mu\mu}$, so the minus sign from lowering lowering the $\mu=0$  index  accounts for the sign difference. Also $c=1$ for most people, so the he wiki may not be consistent, but getting right is easy.

Looking at the Wiki, it is $g^{\mu\nu}$nthat has the $c^{-2}$, and to lower the index you need $g_{\mu\nu}$ which has the $-c^2$, so the wiki article is consistent.

Comment: I looked the wiki article it appears consistten, You did not say that your metric  matrix ``$g$''  was actually the inverse metric. I amended my answer.

Comment: Sorry, question edited. However, still surprised by $u^{\alpha}=(1,0,0,0)$ instead of $u^{\alpha}=(c,0,0,0)$